# Dynamic Sender Profile errored triggered mails

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions, triggered-send, marketingcloudapi

I'm trying to set up a Dynamic Sender Profile and my triggered emails are erroring.
I was told that I simply needed to put %%FromName%% and %%FromEmail%% in the sender profile and then set those two fields in the Data Extension connected to the specific email.
What I have now is:

- Sender profile with %%FromName%% and %%FromEmail%%
- FromName and FromEmail fields in the triggered sendable Data Extension
- FromName and FromEmail fields in the JSON body of the triggered call under SubscriberAttributes

I call the triggered email via POST and it errors.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the ERROR MESSAGE too, it will help the community to debug the issue easily.

Comment: @VishalKumarCV There is no error message in the triggered sends, in the recap I only have Completed/Queued/Errored, and the API response returns "hasErrors: false" and "messages: queued"

Comment: You can debug by doing a subscriber preview of the email against the TSDE - make sure you are using your dynamic sender profile - does it display an error message there?

Comment: @zuzannamj No errors whatsoever in the subscriber preview. The subscriber preview works, and when I try to test send I even receive the "Test send succesfully sent." confirmation popup. Still the email is not delivered.

Comment: Are FromName and FromEmail populated in the TSDE?

Comment: The email address from %%FromEmail%% needs to be verified first. You can go to Email Studio/Admin/From Address Management and enter the email address you did the test send then search to see if it was already verified otherwise you need to do this step

Comment: @zuzannamj Yes of course, they are populated.

Comment: @DucLe Bingo! This was the problem, the FromEmail address wasn't verified. I verified it and now it works flawlessly.

Comment: @DucLe - you should post your comment as an answer, so it can be accepted and upvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your confirmation. I put the answer from my comment above here.

It's likely the email address from `%%FromEmail%%` wasn't verified and it needs to be verified first. You can go to Email Studio/Admin/From Address Management and enter the email address you did the test send then search to see if it was already verified otherwise you need to do this step.

[image]

Comment: For future reference, another way the email can be verified is by going to Marketing Cloud Setup > Platform Tools > Feature Settings > Email Studio > From Address Management. Once here ass the email address and verify it via the link that gets received at that address. There is no difference in the two methods, it is simply another way to do the same thing that someone could find useful.